# Is constexpr the new inline?

Tags: c++

To the best of my knowledge, the `inline` keyword in c++ can be traced back to old compilers (then known as "optimizing compilers") not being able to optimize as well as modern ones, so marking a function as `inline` told the compiler that this should be inlined, and as a side effect prevented ODR issues. As compilers got better, someone realized that the compilers can do a much better job of optimizing than the programmer, and so the `inline` requirement of the compiler became more of a 'hint' that most (all?) modern compilers ignore.

Enter C++11 and subsequent versions. `constexpr` seems to me to be in a similar situation, at least for some of its uses, specifically functions and variables. As I understand it, it tells the compiler that a certain function *may* be evaluated at compile time. But that is something the compiler should be able to figure out on its own. Is this feature also going to become a 'hint' once compilers get better at optimizing?

Note: I am not asking about other uses of `constexpr`, such as with `if` statements. I understand those are needed.

Comment: Although `constexpr` includes some overlapping context with `inline`, `constexpr` is much, much more than that and has nothing to do with optimization.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  But do you think the compiler couldn't just evaluate everything possible at compile time - even things not marked explicitly constexpr and thereby make marking things constexpr just a hint?  Or is there no way for the compiler to know if something should be marked constexpr or not?  I guess what I am asking is: is there a disadvantage to just making everything possible constexpr even if it isn't explicitly marked.

Comment: It's not possible to "making everything possible constexpr", because not everything meets the technical requirements to be a constexpr expression.

Comment: It is not a hint, but the request. It tells that a certain function *must* be evaluated at compile time. If a compiler cannot figure out how to do it (a function does not meet the number of criteria) it raises an error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  That's what I meant by "everything possible"  I guess I could reword it to say "everything mmeting the constexpr requirements"  The question is the same:  Why doesn't the compiler just evaluate at compile time everything that can be, without having to tell it to by marking the stuff constexpr?

Comment: @AskoldIlvento  It isn't an error is it?  It just runs the function at runtime instead, doesn't it?

Comment: Because if you make a mistake, and you explicitly specify that something that `constexpr`, the compiler will catch your mistake and reject the code. And if something is not `constexpr`, there is no law that says that compiler cannot evaluate it at compile time, if possible. And most compiler will actually do that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  If most compiler will actually do that, as you said, then making something constexpr _is_ just a hint to the compiler that you would like it to try.

Comment: Most compilers will do that whether you explicitly specify `constexpr` or not.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Not "a certain function *must* be evaluated at compile time", but "a certain function *must* be evaluatable at compile time". Able to be evaluated, not necessarily actually evaluated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  Thanks very much.  That's what I was trying to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I understand it, it tells the compiler that a certain function *may* be evaluated at compile time.

Not "may", but "can". The `constexpr` keyword does not tell the compiler what it is allowed to do (it *may* evaluate anything it wants at compile time). Rather the keyword tells the compiler a desired quality of the variable or function, specifically that it can be used in [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). The compiler will complain (error or warning) if the program fails to live up to that desire. You get a more relevant error message than you would have gotten otherwise – the compiler can tell you *why* your entity does not qualify for compile-time evaluation since it knows that your intent was for the entity to be a compile-time constant.

*For example, if you defined `const unsigned a`, it is an error to use `std::array<int, a>` if the value of `a` is not known at compile time. The error might be in the initialization of `a`, or it might be that the template parameter was supposed to be `b` instead of `a`. The compiler would have to report the error as "`a` is not a constant expression" and let the programmer investigate. On the other hand, if `a` was declared `constexpr`, the compiler would instead complain about the reason the value of `a` is not known at compile time, leading to less time debugging.*

Without `constexpr`, the following code produces a possibly weak error message.

```cpp
{
    const unsigned a = foo();
    const unsigned b = 42;

    std::array<int, a> stuff;  // Error: 'a' is not a constant expression.
    // ...
}
```

After declaring both `a` and `foo()` to be `constexpr`, the error disappears. Why? Because last week when you wrote `foo()`, the compiler was told that the function had to be usable in constant expressions. As a result, the compiler pointed out why `foo()` could not be evaluated at compile time, and you fixed the bug right away. That was last week, while the implementation of `foo()` was still fresh in your mind. Not this week, after doing a dozen other things, including the hour spent arguing with the compiler because you believed `a` had to be a constant expression since it was initialized with `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

> But that is something the compiler should be able to figure out on its
> own. Is this feature also going to become a 'hint' once compilers get
> better at optimizing?

`constexpr` is not merely an optimization - without
it, the compiler is not allowed to use a function in contexts where a constant expression is required, e.g. in non-type template arguments.

But I am sure you already know that much. The real question is: should a future C++ standard allow using a function in constant expression context even though it is not explicitly marked `constexpr` - in case if it satisfies `contexpr` requirements?

No, I think it is the opposite direction from C++ development. Consider C++20 `concept`. One of its major goals is to improve error messages: instead of going through nested template definitions, the compiler knows early that the template argument does not meet a requirement. Keyword `constexpr` serves the same goal: the compiler, instead of going through a function call tree and finding that a function deep in the call stack cannot be evaluated at compile-time, reports the error early.

Answer (score 2):

An ideal compiler could maybe figure out which functions are actually `constexpr`and in that sense one could view that keyword as a hint to the compiler.

But I think it makes more sense to compare `const` and `constexpr` in terms of what they tell the compiler and the human reader. An ideal compiler could also figure out, which variables and member functions should be `const`. As you probably know, there are other good reasons to mark everything possible `const` (compiler finds bugs for you, much easier to read, helps the compiler in optimization).

The same is true for `constexpr`. If you declare a variable `constexpr`, that cannot be computed at compile time, you get an error, you have documented that the variable can be computed at compile time and it helps the compiler in optimization.

Also note that ignoring `constexpr` does not make sense for runtime performance, which is not true for `inline`.