# c++ why do constexpr functions need to be marked constexpr?

Tags: c++, function, constexpr

This is just a curiosity question.

Why does C++ require functions which otherwise fulfill the requirements of constexpr-ness to be explicitly marked with `constexpr` ?
ie, why not leave `constexpr` off, from a language-design point of view ?

edit: similar question here: [Is constexpr the new inline ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800964/is-constexpr-the-new-inline)

Comment: And how would the compiler know which functions you want to be `constexpr` and which ones you don't?  Just because a function satisfies the requirements of `constexpr` doesn't mean it should automatically *be* `constexpr`. That is why you have to be explicit.  If everything that satisfies `constexpr` were automatically treated as `constexpr`, that would be a lot more processing the compiler has to do at compile-time.

Comment: Imagine you're a library developer. Some your function just happens to fullfill `constexpr` requirements, and users start depending on it. Then one day you change the implementation to something non-`constexpr`, and this becomes a breaking change.

Comment: You are asking this after 10+ years of compiler vendor experience with constant evaluation. When it was proposed, nobody knew that compilers can do so much in constant evaluation. As such, constexpr functions were severely limited. Asking someone to be explicit and opt into the stringent checks was only reasonable.

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau. Compile time is a possibility for sure, but it would be unusual for a compile-time consideration to impact actual design of the language.

Comment: thanks @HolyBlackCat - I considered this, but discarded it because I don't see how a library can provide a compile-time constant function, but it sounds like it can. I'll research along those lines, thanks.

Comment: It's not unusual at all. C++ compilers were notoriously slow (templates were discouraged for a reason). The C++ committee doesn't like adding more oil onto that fire.

Comment: thanks @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. that sounds reasonable.

Comment: .. @HolyBlackCat if the function definition is in a header, then yeah.  API stability makes perfect sense. I was only considering compiled functions.  Reading around a bit I don't see it called-out that you can't have a constexpr function actually defined in a binary .lib or similar, but that has to be the case, right ?   ie, the compiler is not going to fire up some binary library.   ... after some testing w/ VIsualStudio, this seems to be the case: constexpr function needs to be header-only.

Comment: thanks @JaMiT.  yes, it seems to. most salient sentence in there for me: "You get a more relevant error message than you would have gotten otherwise".

Comment: sure, let's close this one as a dupe. thanks again all !