# Why constexpr functions are also inline?

Tags: c++, inline, constexpr

I was wondering why qualifying a function as `constexpr` implies that it must also be `inline`.

Comment: Related: [Is `constexpr` the new inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800964/is-constexpr-the-new-inline)

Comment: I don't think there's a good reason, it just happens to be the case. `inline` does two things: it's an optimization hint, and it removes linker errors on duplicate definitions. The latter is necessary for `constexpr`, as the function definitions need to be visible in each TU that calls them at compile-time. The former isn't necessary. Templates, for example, also don't error on duplicate definitions, but are **not** implicitly inline for optimization purposes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You write _as the function definitions need to be visible in each TU that calls them at compile-time_.
Yes, but you may write a `constexpr` function in a CPP file, used only in this CPP file.
I don't see why a `constexpr` function should have higher chances to be in a .H file than a non `constexpr` function.

Comment: I can't understand why the two concepts (`constexpr` and `inline`) MUST be linked, but I could understand than specifiers of the standard have considered that for most of cases, that would make sense. I just want to be sure there wasn't technical prescrition. It would help me to understand this feature.

Comment: @Oodini `you may write a constexpr function in a CPP file, used only in this CPP file` matches  `each TU that calls them at compile-time`, it this case "each" is "only one". You can do that with inline too. But, code of `constexpr` function can be executed during compilation, that implies greater restrictions than `inline`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, "each" is "only one". So, `inline` is useless. Hence my question. :) For no `constexpr` functions, we have to manually add `inline` when the definition is in a .H file. Why is this different for `constexpr` functions ?

Comment: because, let's say a call to a constexpr function receiving no run-time arguments and returning some value would be mandatory compiled into that final value included into CPU instructions. Which puts for it same requirements as for template function - the definition must be seen. Inline might or might not, depending on optimization startegy. But you can safely take address of constexpr function declared in this unit, it would cause its code to be generated, which you cannot say about inline or template declared in another unit, i.e. it works like inline function otherwise.

Comment: If other unit didn't take address of function, it never was generated (or might never be generated if that's `inline`). It's  optimization of linking stage and that's why inline may cease causing linking conflicts. Difference is that `constexpr` may cease to be such depending or arguments but it stays inline.

Comment: *"don't see why a constexpr function should have higher chances to be in a .H file"* If it's not in a .h file, the extra `inline` does no harm.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't think there's a good reason, it just happens to be the case. `inline` does two things: it's an optimization hint, and it removes linker errors on duplicate definitions. The latter is necessary for `constexpr`, as the function definitions need to be visible in each TU that calls them at compile-time. The former isn't necessary. Templates, for example, also don't error on duplicate definitions, but are **not** implicitly inline for optimization purposes.

–
HolyBlackCat

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918751/why-constexpr-functions-are-also-inline#comment137367667_77918751)